# Have issue in creating polygon on map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, leaflet

We are creating polygon on map it's brake because Road comes between two parcel.

I want to create single polygon. Selected parcel are show in this Polygon but Polygon brake when road comes in map.

I am using turf.union function for creating polygon.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Perhaps you mean to calculate the convex hull or the alpha shape of the selected parcels?

Comment: Thanks lvan,
We need  to create a new polygon by creating a BUFFER that is 200ft around the perimeter of selected parcel. Like Yellow is selected parcel and red line shows as new created parcel. In my case we have parcel coordinates.